# Learning Python - Permutation Error

Tags: python

I'm teaching myself Python.  I saw a java permutation generator from a string, and I figured I use the java version and write the Python version myself.

Here is what I wrote in Python:

```
a = "abc"
a = list(a)

def swap(i,j):
    c = a[i]
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = c

def perm2(n):
    if n == 1:
        print a

    else:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            swap(i, n-1)
            perm2(n-1)
            swap(i, n-1)

perm2(len(a))
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Now, the output does contain all the permutations, but it also contains duplicates.  Yet the java version does not.

What is causing this issue?

**Edit**

By the way, I know I could research and find tools to do this for me in one line, etc...but my goal is to understand the cause of this issue so that the answer will hopefully help me in the future.  Core understanding is important for me.

Comment: You know you can use `itertools.permutations` for this…

Comment: here is a more pythonistic swap: `a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]`

Comment: Yes, but I would like to understand the core of the language, as opposed to blindly using already existing tools.  Trying to learn here, not develop software (yet) -- thanks though, I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Adrien - using your swap, same results, just FYI

Comment: @Sev: yes, it does not correct the problem (that's why i posted that as a comment). it was just to show you a python trick: it uses tuples to swap in-place instead of defining of function using a temporary variable.

Comment: @Adrien, thanks for that trick, it was clever and useful.  appreciate it :)

Comment: But core understanding, of course, is knowing that the function already exists. You just had a language independent error in the algorithm. :)

Comment: In hindsight, it's easy to know that the error was in the algorithm, not syntax.  The way I learn is to code stuff from an old language I know, in a new one, and fix errors.  I couldn't find the error.  Turned out it was algorithmic, but it could have been otherwise.

Comment: You’re perfectly right in getting help in this case be it algorithm or syntax.

Comment: Ok, it's a translation of a Java algorithm, but that's a weird (IMHO) imperative way of generating permutations. It would be a good excercise for you now to write a functional implementation (without in-place statements) using generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change len(a) with n :

```
def perm2(n):
    if n == 1:
        print a
    else:
        for i in range(n):  # << here
            swap(i, n-1) 
            perm2(n-1)
            swap(i, n-1)
```

Result :

```
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you using the itertools

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for perm in itertools.permutations("abc"):
    print perm


('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Comment: -1: the OP clearly stated that he is trying to learn the language.

Comment: I am sorry but, I think he edited his question after I posted the answer.

Comment: Although it wasn't very clearly stated in the question, it was in the comments, much before you posted :) anyway, thanks for the help!